# Multiple moving pictures?

Tags: harry-potter

In Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone, Harry buys a Chocolate Frog from the Trolley Witch. On the back, there is a trading card. It's of Dumbledore, but his picture disappears quickly. When Harry questions Ron, he is told Dumbledore has other places to be:

> Harry turned the card back over and saw, to his astonishment, that
>   Dumbledore's face had disappeared.
>
> "He's gone!"
>
> "Well, you can't expect him to hang around all day," said Ron. "He'll be
>   back."

This means Dumbledore has to travel between pictures. Logical- only one picture version of him. But later, whenever a large piece of news came out, we saw  witches and wizards everywhere reading news on it, in stacks like these:

[image]

Presumably, all of these have the same pictures of people, the same ads, the same of everything. But, if there's only one picture of each person/creature, how can all of these share photos?

Comment: Because the movies are nonsense?

Comment: Because moving ink is very different from an interactive portrait?

Comment: Related (possible duplicate, given the accepted answer): [Why could the pictures and paintings in Hogwarts talk and the photos of Harry's parents couldn't?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/58581/31394)

Comment: This is close to that question, but this is about mass production, not an individual picture.

Comment: See also [What causes the portraits of Wizards to behave interactively?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/12878/31394)

Comment: We've had **LOTS** of [questions about portraits in HP](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=portraits+%5Bharry-potter%5D+is%3Aq) :-)

Comment: Also close, but that is about pictures that there are only one of- my question is why all pictures aren't like that.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I'm trying to decide which this one is the closest dupe of.

Comment: This question is distinguished from the other questions due to it's nature questioning mass - production. While it may appear to be yet another question about why some portraits appear sentient, this question is why some are individuals and others are not.

Comment: @Imperator: I edited in the quote I think you meant.

Comment: A pretty close match to [Why could the pictures and paintings in Hogwarts talk and the photos of Harry's parents couldn't?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58581/why-could-the-pictures-and-paintings-in-hogwarts-talk-and-the-photos-of-harrys?rq=1), surely...

Comment: I think this is a dupe. The only other point to add is that there isn't one Dumbledore shared between all the other chocolate frog cards. So he isn't going to another picture as a a portrait would. He's just going off-screen. Same with the newspapers. They really are just moving photos; they don't capture the personality like a portrait does.

Comment: That, again, is a good point, but if he isn't going anywhere else, why wouldn't he hang around all day? Also, @CHEESE, thanks for the quote.

Comment: @Imperator If the pictures behave at least a bit like their owners (not to the same extent as portraits, tho), the logical conclusion is that picture!Dumbledore is bored.